# Django ORM default values not applied to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, django

I have a field in a Django model that looks like this:

```
median = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I would like this to be equivalent to a MySQL create table query like this:

```
median INT DEFAULT 0
```

However, looking at my db in Sequel Pro, I see there is no default value set. Is there a way to change this behavior, or a smart workaround?

My goal is to be able to insert values into the DB without using the ORM, and still benefit from the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, django implements default values for fields at the time the object is created rather than at the database level. However it's a simple matter to have it both ways. Create a migration.

```
migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY median INT DEFAULT 0;")
```

You will have to do this for all the columns that need to have default values at database level though.